# HibernateSynchronizer uses full package address

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using the [HibernateSynchronizer](http://hibernatesynch.sourceforge.net/) tool in Eclipse Helios.
After using it, the following sample code gets generated in the model and base classes:

```java
private java.lang.String strVariable;
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate the previous code as:

```java
private String strVariable;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `HibernateSynchronizer`. **But Eclipse does have a very good hibernate tool suite available @ http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html.** It is nice to use and will solve the problem you have mentioned. The HQL editor in the tool suite is a good one to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've considered using [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) too but a former colleague of mine (who used it) suggested I use `HibernateSynchronizer`. I'll look into it again though. ...
However, I'd still like to find out if there's any workaround to the problem I've mentioned. :)